# Flushing the BLOB cache best practice

Tags: 2013, powershell, iis

So i need to flush the BLOB cache on our SharePoint 2013 site.
Found the below code on multiple sites but wondering if it should be done out of hours or just during the day.

My limited understanding is that all the files get reset back to 1KB and as people load pages in SharePoint the files are re-stored in the BLOB cache location we have specified. So pages might be initially a little slower to load but then back to normal?

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```

I also came across the fact i should also have the below in there as well, which leads me to believe our side of core hours.

```
iireset
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run an `iisreset`, however you shouldn't flush the cache unless you have good reason to (e.g. an asset on a page isn't updating properly even after a browser cache clear). As you said, there is a performance impact, though it may be small if you have a small environment.

Comment: Image Renditions is saying the BLOB cache is not enabled with multiple sources saying it usually the BLOB being not right. Also getting some Images not displaying for some users. so figured why not.. we have about 2500 people, but the SharePoint in question doesnt have silly traffic through it.

Comment: Sounds good. If you want a GUI to manage this, I do have a solution at https://github.com/Nauplius/BLOBCache/releases/tag/2013-1.8.